# EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. After trying to set up Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am using entity framework code-first design.

For my application a customer should have a creator which is an user from AspNetUser.

Customer Class

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CreatorId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
        public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
    }
```

IdentityModel

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("AgueroCRMDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

After I build I can still register/login but I get this error when trying to access Customers

```
AgueroCRM.Data.Service.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
AgueroCRM.Data.Service.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Line 38:         public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
Line 39:         {
Line 40:             return from r in db.Customer    <-- error occurs here
Line 41:                    orderby r.Id
Line 42:                    select r;
```

Everything was working until I decided to add this foreign key.

Edit: I think this might have something to do with not able to access the IdentityDbContext that contain ApplicationUser from the DbContext that contain Customers.

Anyone know how to solve this?

**Solved:** by merging my ApplicationDbContext into my Main DbContext

```
    public class AgueroCRMDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

        public AgueroCRMDbContext()
            : base("AgueroCRMDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static AgueroCRMDbContext Create()
        {
            return new AgueroCRMDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How is you Startup class? Yesterday i faced to same issue, i forget call services.**AddIdentity**(). You called this method on you Startup class?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<YourIdentityDbContext>(
                options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
                options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;

                }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<UnaIdentityDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();


        }
```